# Why does create-react-app now use a function component for App?

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, react-component

Used to be:

```
class App extends Components{
  //...
}
```

Now `create-react-app` has this in `App.js`:

```
function App(){
  //...
}
```

Anyone know why this change was made? Are they suggesting we shouldn't have state in App?

Answer (score 9):

Since the introduction of hooks in React, you can have state in a function component (cf. [useState](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html)).

According to [React 16.x roadmap post](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/11/27/react-16-roadmap.html), it might be a good move to slowly transition class components to function components:

> Hooks don’t deprecate classes. However, if Hooks are successful, it is possible that in a future major release class support might move to a separate package, reducing the default bundle size of React.

Comment: actually they are called **function** components, not functional components. Class components also tend to be functional in some cases, and even though they are classic components nobody calls them classical ;)

Answer (score 0):

The class Components were not very reusable, and they were lacking a sense of interchangeability. It will be ideal to use move away from class components and start using function components. refer to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55887544/how-to-create-react-js-app-without-a-function-in-app-js/58848051#58848051)